# Compare same columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to compare data and return rows that have one of the column values lower than the other, the thing is the value is different every time, best shown in example, I have a problem to describe that in theory:

So I need to select everything that every boy like more than swimming (sort order describe order of likes, 1 = most liked). I have 2 tables, one with Kid names and gender, second with sports the kid likes, as below.

The order for each kid may be different, always I need the results of what they like more than Swimming.

Kids table:

| Name | ID | Age | Sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kate | 1 | 15 | F |
| John | 2 | 16 | M |
| Tom | 3 | 6 | M |

Kids_sports table

| Kid_ID | Sport | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | football | 1 |
| 1 | baseball | 3 |
| 1 | basketball | 5 |
| 1 | golf | 4 |
| 1 | Swimming | 2 |
| 2 | Swimming | 2 |
| 2 | golf | 1 |
| 2 | basketball | 3 |
| 3 | VolleyBall | 1 |
| 3 | Skiing | 3 |
| 3 | golf | 2 |
| 3 | Swimming | 4 |

From above data I should get result:

| Kids.Name | Kids_sports.Sport |
| --- | --- |
| John | Golf |
| Tom | VolleyBall |
| Tom | Skiing |
| Tom | golf |

I don't see any simple solution for this - I'm thinking right now about splitting this into different queries:

1. Find boys and how much each of them likes swimming
2. Find what each boy like more than swimming by running query separately for each boy and saving the results

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I havn't run this, but its the approach I would take:

```
SELECT kids.name
       , other_sports.sport
FROM kids
JOIN kids_sports swimming
    ON kids.id = swimming.kid_id
       AND sport = 'Swimming'
LEFT JOIN kids_sports other_sports
    ON kids.id = other_sports.kid_id
       AND other_sports.[ORDER] > swimming.[order];
```

You want to know what each kids swimming order is by joining to the sports table for just that, then using the order for the swimming, select from other_sports everything that has a higher order value.

I've used `[ ]` around `order` as its a keyword in SQL server.

Stylistically I could put the `AND swimming.sport = 'Swimming'` into a where clause, but I feel this demonstrates what I'm trying to do here better.

I'm using left joins so that if the kids favourite sport is swimming they'd still appear in your results with null favourite sports. Making that into an inner join would hide that, depending on what you are after there

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a class exercise. Here's pseudo-code that probably fits the assignment:

```
select ...
from kids inner join kid sports ... 
where order < (
    select order from kid sports ks2
    where <correlated match on kid id> and ks2.sport = 'swimming'
);
```

An advanced approach:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        min(case when sport = 'swimming' then order end) over (partition by k.id) as swim_pref
    from kids k inner join kids_sports is on ks.Kid_ID = k.ID
)
select * from data
where order < swim_pref;
```